# i don't know how to show output of code on graphic console in dev c++?

Tags: c++, bgi

i want to show the output of code on graphic console in graphics.h. here is the code below that i want to show on graphic console

```
if(userinput == "1"){
        cout<<"you choose addition\n";
        cout<<"please enter your calculation : \n\n";
        initwindow (600,600);
        //creating rectangle
        rectangle(40,70,410,290 );
        cout<<"enter first number plzz:";
        cin>>num1;
        cout<<"enter sign of addition operator:";
        cin>>mathop;
        cout<<"enter second number";
        cin>>num2;
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Where do you want to show it? You have to decide what you want first. Did you read the documentation for your "graphics" API?

Comment: i am beginner i don't know too much about c++